# Use session variable to not display modal popup on every page visit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, session, popup

Is there a way to use a session variable (not a browser cookie) to not display a modal popup from CEWP on every page load?

Answer (score 0):

BGill,

Your question seems to be a possible duplicate of:
[Prompt My Site users to accept Terms of Use Agreement on first visit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/prompt-my-site-users-to-accept-terms-of-use-agreement-on-first-visit)
OR 
[How to create Terms & Conditions page before the user visit content on the site in publsihing site.If it is his first login](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/96d2451b-8379-47af-bd8d-d0da34ce8d32)

I hope one of these should help you!

Comment: Unfortunately, both links provided come close but do not provide the total solution.  I'm wanting this to be done in a hidden CEWP, session variable stored until the user logs out and the session is destroyed.